# What does Cdf / Cdf[-1] do when cdf represents a Cumulative distribution function built from a cv2.calcHist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, np, cdf

I am trying to decipher a block of code that was completed by a freelancer and I keep getting stuck on this one part. I can't go into too much detail about this code but what I can say is that he is creating a new variable inside of a def run(self). Let's name it "Result". and then taking a np.cumsum(histogram) let's call it "HistCumSum" and performing the following operation --> Result = HistCumSum / HistCumSum[-1]

I have searched google for about a week and tried to print out the numerical values/ hand do the math and it makes no sense

```
 HistCumSum = np.cumsum(Hist)

 Result = HistCumSum / HistCumSum[-1]
```

I am unable to explain what the result is used for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HistCumSum[-1]` is the final value in the array `HistCumSum`. Because `HistCumSum` is a cumulative sum we can see `Result = HistCumSum / HistCumSum[-1]` as *normalising* from a cumulative *frequency* to a cumulative *distribution function*.

Having a look at what `Hist`, `HistCumSum` and `Result` look like might help to clear things up:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, num=100)
# Evaluate pdf in lieu of actual data
Hist = norm.pdf(x)

# Compute cumulative sum
HistCumSum = np.cumsum(Hist)
# Normalise cumulative sum to produce cdf
Result = HistCumSum / HistCumSum[-1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=[7, 3])
ax[0].plot(x, Hist)
ax[1].plot(x, HistCumSum)
ax[2].plot(x, Result)
ax[0].set_title('Hist')
ax[1].set_title('HistCumSum')
ax[2].set_title('Results (CDF)')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. How does that math work? If you have the array [1,2,3,4,5], array[-1] would be just the value 5?  So essentially it's just dividing the original array by 5?

Comment: Also, what is cumulative density? isn't that a contradictory phrase, cumulative density?

Comment: @TylerG Exactly. You're diving the original array by the final value. When I said cumulative density I meant the cumulative distribution function, ie the CDF

Comment: I'm incredibly new to numpy and cv2 so pardon me if these are basic questions but would that mean that the original cumsum of the histogram was the frequency and by dividing by the final value in the frequency, you get the CDF?

Comment: @TylerG Yes, the cumsum of the histogram was the *cumulative* frequency. When you divide by the final value you get the CDF. I've added some plots to my answer which may help.